# Create Database connection from scratch

Tags: database

I know there are many libraries to connect to the database today, that programmers easily connect to database.

I just wonders how to make it from scratch because I heard programmers in 80's or 90's, they had to make manually library connection to database.

Comment: You could look into the source code of those libraries, and keep going down the dependency tree. In the end you will get the basic implementation of those libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here are few steps which should be executed to make that beginner level of lib.

- Database connectivity function (I am using `PHP` to answer)
- Host name, User Name, Password and DB Name which we want to connect
- Get Instance by executing that function call with parameters
- if return is TRUE or Instance, means database connected
- if return is FALSE, means database credentials are wrong, database is not there, port is not available or any reason.

  - $dbConn = mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database)
  - if(!$dbConn) then show error message.
- Then you need to make few functions to get info like:

  - getAllRecords($tableName)
  - getRecordOnId($tableName, $recordId)
  - deleteRecord($tableName, $recordId)
  - addRecord($tableName, $data)
  - updateRecord($tableName, $data, $recordId)

and customize functions can be defined as per need.